# Generate Kafka records from a large input file using Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Using KStream::flatTransformValues it is possible to convert a single message on a source topic to multiple messages on a destination topic. However my use case is that I need to read the contents of a possibly large file and write the contents to a topic. The function flatTransformValues uses an Iterable to make the split, but this means that I would need to have an enormous amount of data in memory.

Is there a way to use a streaming method so that I can process large input files?

Here's part of my code:

```
KStream<String, String> messageStream = streamsBuilder
        .stream("sourceTopic", Consumed.with(STRING_SERDE, STRING_SERDE))
        .flatTransformValues(new ValueTransformerWithKeySupplier<>() {
    @Override
    public ValueTransformerWithKey<String, String, Iterable<String>> get() {
        return new ValueTransformerWithKey<>() {

            ProcessorContext context;

            @Override
            public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            public Iterable<String> transform(String s, String fileToRead) {
                log.info("Reading " + fileToRead);

                return (Iterable<String>) readFileService.readFile(fileToRead).iterator();
            }

            @Override
            public void close() {

            }
        };
    }

})
        .to("destinationTopic");
```

Comment: Sure, Java NIO can create a Stream of strings from a file. That has nothing to do with Kafka Streams. What issues are you running into?

Comment: This question is specifically about Kafka Streams. I have a source topic which receives events about incoming files, and an destination topic that should receive a message for each line in those files. As the files can be large, I don't want to read the entire file into memory. I wonder if Kafka Streams has something for that.

Comment: Like, I said, after the event is consumed, it has nothing to do with Kafka Streams. Yes, Java can read files. No, Kafka Streams has no functions for file management/processing. Again, what have you tried and what issues are you having coding this?